# Mongodb returns base64 value with its function in the string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

so I used gridfs to store an image on mongodb and when I want to get the images value in b64 it returns its function too. Here is how it looks:

`Binary.createFromBase64(base64ValueHere)`
instead of just returning the value itself.

I read the docs and when I try:
`myCollection.binaryObjectsFromBase64.findOne( { _id: fileId } )`
I get the following error:

```
await chunksCollection.binaryObjectsFromBase64.findOne({files_id: filesResult._id})
                                                                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findOne')
```

And this is how I am trying to retreive the file:

```
const getCourseImage = async (req, res) => {
    const courseId = req.params.courseId;

    if (courseId.length !== 24) {
        throw new InvalidInputError("Invalid course Id.");
    }
      
    const course = await Course.findById(courseId);

    if (!course) {
        throw new NotFoundError("Course not found");
    }

    const db = mongoose.connection.db;

    if(!db) {
        throw new Error("Could not connect to databas");
    }

    const filesCollection = db.collection("uploads.files");

    if(!filesCollection) {
        throw new NotFoundError("Could not find collection")
    }

    const filesResult = await filesCollection.findOne({filename: course.image});

    if(!filesResult){
        throw new NotFoundError("Image not found")
    }

    const chunksCollection = db.collection("uploads.chunks")

    const chunksResult = await chunksCollection.findOne({files_id: filesResult._id})

    console.log(chunksResult)
    const binaryData = Buffer.from(imageData, 'base64');
    res.contentType('image/jpeg');

    res.send(binaryData);
   
};
```

This is also my gridfs storage settings:

```
const multer = require('multer');
const {GridFsStorage} = require('multer-gridfs-storage');
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

const storage = new GridFsStorage({
    url: 'mongodb://moonstruck:moonstruck@localhost:27018/moonstruck',
    file: (req, file) => {
        const filename = `${uuidv4()}.${file.originalname.split('.').pop()}`;
        return {
        filename: filename,
        bucketName: 'uploads',
        };
    },
}); 


const upload = multer({ storage });

module.exports = upload;
```

I need to fix this so I can turn the b64 to buffer so I can send an image as a response but the image now has errors because of the function in the base64 string. Thanks!

Comment: Assuming [this](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/Binary.createFromBase64/#retrieve-document-from-collection-with-binary-object) is the documentation you mean, that example assumes a collection named binaryObjectsFromBase64, and the example is for mongosh.  If you edit the question and add the code you are using to retrieve the data, we might be able to help fix it.

Comment: Thanks for a clarification on that one, edited. I am also not sure if the image should be saved in base64 at all or directly in binary format. Not sure why that happens.